# Anyway to extract data drop pin data from google map link (fusion table)

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

This link is random, but say i wanted to pull the droppin data from this map.  looks like its a list of libraries.  Anyway to do it?

https://fusiontables.googleusercontent.com/fusiontables/embedviz?q=select+col1+from+1pnaSGefHDOEqRbmdl-Pscio8UR1rDARbsAHFqY1U&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=9.265891742631307&lng=-32.723723968441185&t=3&z=2&l=col1&y=2&tmplt=2&hml=ONE_COL_LAT_LNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can.

try this

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1pnaSGefHDOEqRbmdl-Pscio8UR1rDARbsAHFqY1U#rows:id=1

the key is to copy the docid to view in fusion table.

Comment: thanks so much, this is exactly what i was looking for.  For some reason i could not for the life of me find any info in the documentation.